# How to count time in specific time range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem with counting time in a given time interval. I want to count only those minutes that are in a row for example 5 minutes. For example, we do not count the time between 19:46-19:51 yes.

The first idea was to add values to the array if the length of the interval in which there is no break.

```
2019-05-14 19:26:00,144.1639344262295
2019-05-14 19:27:00,138.54098360655738
2019-05-14 19:46:00,137.45901639344262
2019-05-14 19:47:00,139.24590163934425
2019-05-14 19:49:00,161.0
2019-05-14 19:50:00,145.90322580645162
2019-05-14 19:51:00,145.327868852459
2019-05-14 20:18:00,150.95081967213116
2019-05-14 20:19:00,155.80645161290323
2019-05-14 20:20:00,155.5737704918033
2019-05-14 20:21:00,155.0327868852459
2019-05-14 20:22:00,157.70491803278688
2019-05-14 20:23:00,156.5483870967742
2019-05-14 20:24:00,155.62295081967213
2019-05-14 20:25:00,156.1451612903226
2019-05-14 20:26:00,152.65
2019-05-14 20:27:00,157.8548387096774
2019-05-14 20:28:00,156.01639344262296
2019-05-14 20:29:00,156.6290322580645
2019-05-14 20:30:00,156.44262295081967
```

Expected results: 13 minutes time between 20:18 to 20:30.

Do you have an idea of how to do something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by `count`? Can you show expected result?

Comment: I assume your question has sth to do with consecutive minutes ranges. so: why  19:46 to 19:51 if there is no 19:48?

Comment: @SpghttCd Right, my error! Yes, only between 20:18 to 20:30.

Comment: So still open question: what do you mean by "`count`"? Do you really just want to add all ranges with consecutive minutes, which are minimum 5min long? Or do you want to have a dataframe cleaned from all other entries?

Comment: @SpghttCd Better option: a dataframe cleaned from all other entries.

Comment: Then please: rewrite your question so that it asks what you want in a way, that people who did not think about the same problems like you the last few days can understand, where you stuck. BTW speaking of stuck: Could you please add your attempt and some code which doesn't work, so that we can help you getting forward...? (see [ask] and [mcve])

Comment: Background: As you can see, the answers are otherwise full of assumptions. The first silently assumes that your datetime data and your value data are both dataframe columns and the index is just not shown. Besides that, they simply name the columns 0 and 1 - why? nobody knows. The next assumes, datetime is the index. Here the only column is named a. Only cos theres no info from you about that, random matter of taste. Both assume, datetime is already of type `datetime`, while I'm pretty sure that everythin is still `string` - but I can't know because you didn't say. and so on, and so on........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) between values and create groups by compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
#if DatetimeIndex
g = df.index.to_series().diff().ne(pd.Timedelta('1Min')).cumsum()
#if column dates
g = df['dates'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta('1Min')).cumsum()
```

then for count is possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), compare for greater and `sum` only `True` values:

```
out = g.map(g.value_counts()).gt(5).sum()
print (out)
13
```

If need filter rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[g.map(g.value_counts()).gt(5)]
print (df1)
                              a
2019-05-14 20:18:00  150.950820
2019-05-14 20:19:00  155.806452
2019-05-14 20:20:00  155.573770
2019-05-14 20:21:00  155.032787
2019-05-14 20:22:00  157.704918
2019-05-14 20:23:00  156.548387
2019-05-14 20:24:00  155.622951
2019-05-14 20:25:00  156.145161
2019-05-14 20:26:00  152.650000
2019-05-14 20:27:00  157.854839
2019-05-14 20:28:00  156.016393
2019-05-14 20:29:00  156.629032
2019-05-14 20:30:00  156.442623
```

If need output in new `DataFrame` you can aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
#if DatetimeIndex
#df = df.rename_axis('dates').reset_index()
g = df['dates'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta('1Min')).cumsum()

df1 = (df[g.map(g.value_counts()).gt(5)]
        .groupby(g)['dates']
        .agg([('start','first'),('end','last'),('count','size')])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
                start                 end  count
0 2019-05-14 20:18:00 2019-05-14 20:30:00     13
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
blocks = df[0].diff().dt.seconds.ne(60).cumsum()
blocks.groupby(blocks).apply(lambda x: len(x) if len(x)>=5 else 0).sum()
# 13
```

If you want the actual block:

```
df['block'] = df[0].diff().dt.seconds.ne(60).cumsum()
df.groupby('block').apply(lambda x: x if len(x) >=5 else None).dropna()
```

Output:

```
    0                       1           block
7   2019-05-14 20:18:00     150.950820  4.0
8   2019-05-14 20:19:00     155.806452  4.0
9   2019-05-14 20:20:00     155.573770  4.0
10  2019-05-14 20:21:00     155.032787  4.0
11  2019-05-14 20:22:00     157.704918  4.0
12  2019-05-14 20:23:00     156.548387  4.0
13  2019-05-14 20:24:00     155.622951  4.0
14  2019-05-14 20:25:00     156.145161  4.0
15  2019-05-14 20:26:00     152.650000  4.0
16  2019-05-14 20:27:00     157.854839  4.0
17  2019-05-14 20:28:00     156.016393  4.0
18  2019-05-14 20:29:00     156.629032  4.0
19  2019-05-14 20:30:00     156.442623  4.0
```